# How to extract the hour of day from an epoch and count each instance that occurs during that hour?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question that I feel is pretty straight forward but is giving me some issues.

I have a column in table X called `event_time` which is an epoch. I am wanting to extract the hour of day out of that and count the number of rides that have occurred during that hour.

So the output will end up being a bar chart with x values 0-24 and the Y being the number of instances that occur (which is bike rides for example).

Here is what I have now, that isn't giving me the correct output:

```
select extract(hour from to_timestamp(start_time)::date) as hr,
count(*) as ct
from x 
group by hr 
order by hr asc
```

Any hints or help are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Lose the `::date` and you will probably get what you want.  Casting to `date` will end up with a time of `00:00:00` which what the `hour` will be extracted from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arithmetic:

```
select floor( (start_time % (24 * 60 * 60)) / (60 * 60) ) as hour,
       count(*)
from x
group by hour;
```

Or convert to a date/time and extract the hour:

```
select extract(hour from '1970-01-01'::date + start_time * interval '1 second') as hour, count(*)
from x
group by hour;
```

Comment: The first option to use arithmetic worked great, thank you!

Comment: Your second option would convert the hour to a `UTC` time, which might be confusing if you are expecting local time. Wouldn't it be better to do: `select extract(hour from to_timestamp(start_time));`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver . . . That is an interesting point.  The question doesn't actually mention the time zone and the first method (which seems to meet the OP's needs) would return UTC hour.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments! So, I am now actually wanting to change to a local time, which in this case is central standard (CST). Can I set the time zone with something like this? ```select (extract(hour from to_timestamp(start_time)) at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'CST'```?

Comment: @dwool . . . Epoch time is defined at UTC.  You might want to ask another question to be clearer on how you want timezones expressed.

Comment: Ahh okay, I will do that then. Thanks for your help Gordon! This is for a client, basically we get the data as a epoch and I assume they want it transformed into their local time.